# Importing modules, Levenshtein

Tags: python, import, easy-install, levenshtein-distance

I'm working on a script that uses comparisons to determine fuzzy-matching, so I'm using the Levenshtein feature.

Unfortunately, when I run easy_install python-Levenshtein in the Terminal window, Python still doesn't recognize Levenshtein when I run an import on it. When I look at the terminal window, I get these list of error codes (I think this is where it's going wrong):

> Processing python-Levenshtein-0.10.2.tar.gz
>
> Running python-Levenshtein-0.10.2/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir  /var/folders/0H/0HiEtyHBGV4TWfq84ctWC++++TM/-Tmp-/easy_install-tbdn73/python-Levenshtein-0.10.2/egg-dist-tmp-L7Jws0
> warning: no files found matching '*' under directory 'docs'
>
> warning: no previously-included files matching '*pyc' found anywhere in distribution
>
> warning: no previously-included files matching '.project' found anywhere in distribution
>
> warning: no previously-included files matching '.pydevproject' found anywhere in distribution
>
> unable to execute gcc-4.0: No such file or directory
>
> error: Setup script exited with error: command 'gcc-4.0' failed with exit status 1

Does anyone know why the Levenshtein install isn't working? I think it has something to do with the gcc-4.0 error (I ran a GCC installer, but it still doesn't work), or have any suggestions?

Comment: what OS is this? On ubuntu, `apt-get install python-levenshtein` will install it from apt.

Comment: have you tried downloading the package manually and trying to compile it?

Comment: @user1389884, note that there's also the built-in Python module [`difflib`](http://docs.python.org/library/difflib.html) which provides some fuzzy-matching and edit-distance functionality.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The giveaway is this line:

```
unable to execute gcc-4.0: No such file or directory
```

This is a hint that you don't have the OS X developer tools installed. You'll need to download them from Apple. If you're lucky, you'll be able to find a download for the command-line tools only, which is all you need - otherwise you'll have to download the whole of XCode, which is several gigabytes.

Answer (score 2):

You probably have to install Python's dev packages to be able to compile the C code in this package. To install python-dev on a Debian/Ubuntu machine, simply run:

```
sudo apt-get install python-dev
```

If the speed of calculating the distances is not your concern you could also look at pure Python implementations, for example the [nltk.metrics.distance](http://nltk.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/api/nltk.metrics.distance-module.html) module that can be found in NLTK.

Comment: I assumed that you are using something different than OS X. Sorry, my bad. Daniel Roseman has the correct answer. Again, if you just want to calculate Levenstein without installing the OS X dev tools, you coudl have a look at NLTK or have a look at this simple example: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_Implementation/Strings/Levenshtein_distance#Python